# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'items' referenced before assignment - Python3

Tags: python-3.x

When I enter a words, the code in the except block won't run.
it says: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'items' referenced before assignment
Here's my Code:

```
def inputSome():
    gundam = []
    try:
        items = int(input("How many items you want to input? \n"))

    except ValueError:
        print("Input a number literal not words u stupid!, you input {}".format(items))
        inputSome()
    while len(gundam) < items:
        userIn = input("Input some: ")
        gundam.append(userIn)
        print("You input: {}".format(userIn))

    print(gundam)

    input_again = input("Want to input again? [Y/N] ")
    if input_again.lower() != 'n':
        inputSome()
    else:
        print("See ya sucka!")
inputSome()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception happens during the calculation of `int(input("How many items you want to input? \n"))` so items never gets assigned a value and therefore you got this error.

If you want to get what the user typed in your error message, just split into another line.

```
raw_items = input("How many items you want to input? \n")
items = int(raw_items)
```